# Importing multiple movie clips inside one directory via script

Tags: python, scripting

I want to import multiple movie files via script and add an offset to each file. What I came up with so far returns an error:

"Python script fail, look in the console for now"
but there is nothing in the console.

```
import os, bpy, sys    
from bpy import context
scene = context.scene

path = "/Volumes/Temp/Grau_Benjamin/VIDEO/STab_Kippe_Einzelbilder"

files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()

file_start_increase = 12
end = 5
i = 0 # count variable


# create the sequencer data

scene.sequence_editor_create()

while i <= end :

    starta = i * 48 + i * file_start_increase

    print (frame_range_back_start)

    bpy.ops.sequencer.movie_strip_add(
                filepath=os.path.join(path, files[i]),
                channel=i + 1, frame_start=starta)

    i += 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101120/selecting-sequences-in-vse-via-python/101129#) IMO it's far easier to add strips  using API methods.

Comment: You mean strips as in image strips? I have a folder of 72 datamoshed avi files. I thought to import them directly would be a huge timesaver.

Comment: I mean strips as in sequencer strips, click the manual link above. This one   [`new_movie(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Sequences.html#bpy.types.Sequences.new_movie) looks promising. Replace the operator in your code with it. If error persists [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/111446/edit) error into your question. (copy text from system console)

Comment: looks really good, but how do I implement it? Sorry I'm really bad at this, I just try to find and copy code.
py.types.sequences.new_movie("test",
                filepath=os.path.join(path, files[i]),
                channel=i + 1, frame_start=starta)
If I do it like this I get still an error message.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46903/how-to-view-python-error-messages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Glob all movie files in a folder**

Below is a script to [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob) all movie files in a given folder, and add them to the VSE as movie strips using [`Sequencer.new_movie`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Sequences.html#bpy.types.Sequences.new_movie) an offset of 12 is added to start frame of each. Edit to suit.

Note the use of `bpy.path.extensions_movie` Blender's list of movie types it can open.  For my blender

```
>>> bpy.path.extensions_movie
frozenset({'.mpg2', '.mov', '.avi', '.vob', '.flc', '.mpeg', '.movie',
 '.avs', '.xvid', '.webm', '.mv', '.ogg', '.r3d', '.dv', '.mp4',
 '.flv', '.m2ts', '.mts', '.wmv', '.mpg', '.divx', '.ogv', '.mxf',
 '.mkv', '.m2t', '.m4v', '.ts', '.m2v'})
```

The script.

```
import bpy
import os, glob

# glob all movie files from
vid_dir = "/home/batfinger/Videos"
exts = bpy.path.extensions_movie
files = [f for ext in exts for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(vid_dir, "*%s" % ext))]
files.sort()

# get sequence editor
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.sequence_editor_create()
seq = scene.sequence_editor.sequences

# add movie strips
for i, fp in enumerate(files):
    frame_start = i * 12 # some offset 
    name = os.path.basename(fp)
    ms = seq.new_movie(
            name=name,
            filepath=fp,
            channel=i,
            frame_start=frame_start
            )
    # print some details
    print("%s ch: %d fs: %3.1f len: %d" %
            (name, i, frame_start, ms.frame_final_duration)
            )
```

**[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)**

Script in question had simple python errors, in that you were trying to print an undefined variable. [How to view python error messages?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46903/how-to-view-python-error-messages)

For python questions like finding all files in a folder, or sorting lists strongly recommend searching on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) via google.  Eg this search

```
site:stackoverflow.com python list all files in folder
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the import is working. The files are out of order though. How do I fix that?