# How to insert a keyframe in the VSE via script?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

I have the following code in which I want to add a keyframe at two points at the end:

```
import bpy
import os, glob

# glob all movie files from
vid_dir = "/Volumes/Temp/Grau_Benjamin/01_avi_sequences_264frames_backw/0_glitched/"
# note this will recursively find movies in folder
exts = bpy.path.extensions_movie
files = [f for ext in exts for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(vid_dir, "*%s" % ext))]
files.sort()


scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.sequence_editor_create()
seq = scene.sequence_editor.sequences
for i, fp in enumerate(files):
    frame_start = (i * 48) + (i * i) + 1# some offset 
    name = os.path.basename(fp)
    seq.new_movie(name=name,
                  filepath=fp,
                  channel=32 - i,
                  frame_start=frame_start
                  )
    scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[name].blend_type = 'CROSS'
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = frame_start + ((i+1) * 48) + ((i+1) * (i+1)) + 1
    scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[name].blend_alpha = 100
    # Here I want to set a keyframe for the blend parameter
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = frame_start + ((i+2) * 48) + ((i+2) * (i+2)) + 1
    scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[name].blend_alpha = 0
    # Here I want to set a keyframe for the blend parameter
```

I tried using the automatic keyframe insertion, but this wouldn't work. And I don't see what's happening inside the console, so that I could paste it to my code, when doing it manually.

Thank you very much.

Benni

Answer (score 1):

**Keyframe insert**

In a late edit to [previous answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/111455/15543) I wanted to point out that the sequencers [`new_movie(..)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=keyframe_insert#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert) method returns the newly created strip. (In the docs from the link where it says "*Returns*") Assigned it to variable `ms`

The context scene alreasy is assigned to `scene`.  Hence there is no need for `bpy.context.scene.sequences_all[name]...`  Doing it this way will cause problems if there already a strip named "foo", the new one will be named "foo.001" and you will be looking at old one instead. This is one big reason to use API methods that return a reference to the object they've created.

There are oodles of questions and answers on bse re adding keyfraems using [`keyframe_insert(datapath, frame)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=keyframe_insert#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert) which can be used like

```
# set the value
ob.foo_bar = 22
# insert the keyframe at frame f
ob.keyframe_insert("foo_bar", frame=f)
```

There is no need to change the `scene.frame_current` first.

Ammended code.

```
import bpy
import os, glob

# glob all movie files from
vid_dir = "/home/batfinger/Videos/"
# note this will recursively find movies in folder
exts = bpy.path.extensions_movie
files = [f for ext in exts for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(vid_dir, "*%s" % ext))]
files.sort()

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.sequence_editor_create()
seq = scene.sequence_editor.sequences
for i, fp in enumerate(files):
    frame_start = (i * 48) + (i * i) + 1# some offset 
    name = os.path.basename(fp)
    ms = seq.new_movie(name=name,
                  filepath=fp,
                  channel=32 - i,
                  frame_start=frame_start
                  )
    ms.blend_type = 'CROSS'
    f = frame_start + ((i+1) * 48) + ((i+1) * (i+1)) + 1
    ms.blend_alpha = 100
    ms.keyframe_insert("blend_alpha", frame=f)

    f = frame_start + ((i+2) * 48) + ((i+2) * (i+2)) + 1
    ms.blend_alpha = 0
    ms.keyframe_insert("blend_alpha", frame=f)
```

To see what's happening you need to print something (or throw an error)

```
print("this will be seen in system console (terminal)")
```