# How can I script images processing of multiple images?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, eevee-render-engine

Let's say I've got a node set-up that does some arbitrary image processing on an image texture and I have 20 images I want to process.

I'm looking to create a script that tells my Blend file to look in X folder, grab the first image, process it, save it with a new name in the same folder, and move on to the next image?

Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat related, grabs all movies type files in a folder and adds as strips in VSE.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/111455/15543

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. Reading code is probably the best way to start.

Comment: check this out: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218730/automatically-generate-100-animations-each-with-a-different-texture-input-blen

Comment: Thanks! I need to spend some time with the code and test it out, but it seems conceptually pretty similar to my situation. Thank you!