# How can I import the first 30 frames from a folder of video files in Blender using a script

Tags: python, scripting

I have some dashcam footage from a road trip I took recently with around 300 video files. I'd like to take the first 30 frames or approx 1 second of each of these video files as a kind of time lapse video. I'd like to do this using a Python script as manually importing and cutting the 300 clips would be extremely time consuming.

I have found the script [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111446/importing-multiple-movie-clips-inside-one-directory-via-script) to import the files, but I can't figure out how to modify this cut the clips to just the first 1 sec of footage. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.

````
import bpy

seqs = bpy.context.sequences

for seq in seqs:
    start_frame = seq.frame_start
    new_end_frame = start_frame + 30
    seq.frame_final_end = new_end_frame

bpy.ops.sequencer.gap_remove(all=True)

```
````

Comment: I was able to resolve this by using this code to update the original script with this line of code 

ms.frame_final_end = frame_start + 30