# How to add multiple images as a strip in the video editting with python?

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I am trying to automate a process whereby I add specific images as a strip in my video editing.
So far I figured out how to do this for individual pictures,

'scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_image('p01', '/real_path_to_file/000.jpg',1,1)'

but not for multiple images.
Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101129/15543  To clarify do you want to add an image sequence or multiple image strips? If the latter use a loop  `for image_path in image_paths:` ...

Comment: I can't remember who did this slideshow snippet. I just made a gist copy sometime in the past. Maybe you'll find it useful: https://gist.github.com/tin2tin/fd09d580eabc791700731497d6ca6916